# how to run multiple sp file using spectre

Tags: tcl, cadence, cadence-virtuoso

I have a bunch of `.sp` files that need to be simulated with Cadence Spectre. Instead of `run spectre` as --

```
run spectre 1.sp->exit->run spectre 2.sp->exit->...
```

-- is there some kind of **batch mode** in Spectre so that i can **launch Spectre once and execute these tasks sequentially (hold the spectre and run next task)**? How can I achieve this?

I need this because each time launching the Spectre it needs check the license and does other things, costing unnecessary time.

Thanks in advance.

error message:

```
invalid command name "if{!0}"
while executing
"if{![eof $log]} {
    puts [gets $log]
  } else {
    close $log
    incr event_flag
  }"
    (procedure "GetData" line 3)
    invoked from within
"GetData file3"
can't wait for variable "event_flag": would wait forever
    while executing
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use open command in tool interactive mode

```
#!/bin/sh  
# \
exec tclsh "$0" ${1+"$@"}

set event_flag 0 

proc GetData {log} {
    global event_flag
    if {![eof $log]} {
        puts [gets $log]
    } else {
        close $log
        incr event_flag
    }
}

# Run the following in loop   
set log [open "|spectre 1.sp"]
fconfigure $log -blocking 0
fileevent $log readable [ list GetData $log ]
vwait event_flag
```

Comment: Hi Roman, thank you very much for answering, but can you be much specific? I didn’t see there’s an open option when entered spectre interactive mode.

Comment: Just try to run the example for one interaction.
The script will not continue till "spectre 1.sp" will not finished. Then wrap last 4 lines of code in loop , you only need to change 1.sp to 2.sp , etc.

Comment: Run the example you mean put them in a tcl file and run it with tclsh right? I just ran the example in tclsh, it gives “GetData file3” can’t wait for variable “event_flag”:would wait forever.

Comment: @LGMchili I've updated the example. Please try to run it as executable tcl file

Comment: it still reports the same err, did i miss something? i put the error message in the question, this is kind of important to me, please help me out. thanks a lot...

Comment: @LGMchili I've run my example with spectre , to be honest I'm not familiar with this tool, so I've used some spice file and it work as expected. I mean, I didn't get your error message. Please try to re-check your code.

Comment: The error message in the question is because you need a space between `if` and `{`.

Comment: This just runs spectre multiple times, multiple license checkouts.